# Chrome launching twice when running a Cucumber feature

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, bdd

I have a problem where Chrome driver is launching twice when I run a feature file.

I'm using Cucumber with Selenium Java using IntelliJ.

The problem came about when I created a new stepdef file for a new area of functionality that I'm working on. So I'm pretty sure this is something to do with how the features are linked to step defs. I'm still learning the ropes here so this is an area I haven't had much experience in.

My Step Defs each come with @Before code to run before every stepdef method and the @Before code contains a

```
driver.get("https://mywebsite_under_test");
```

This website URL is different for each of the two StepDef files.

When I launch my test I can see that the two chrome sessions it starts are the ones mentioned in the @Before of each Step Def file. I'm launching from the IDE where I just run the feature.

My project structure is as follows:

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   └───resources
└───test
    ├───java
    │   ├───Database
    │   ├───Pages
    │   └───stepdefs
    │       ├───MOPStepDefs
    │       └───MOSStepDefs
    └───Resources
        ├───MOP Features
        └───MOS Features
```

I'm out of ideas here. I've messed about with Glue value in the Config but not getting any luck.

Comment: With your before tag add the scenario tag so it only runs when you run that scenario i.e. @Before("@MOP") where @MOP is a tag of your feature or scenario. Alternatively create a hooks file and move your before step into there and calculate which url to use based on the scenario tag. First option above is easier.

Comment: Add the codes for driver initialization.

Comment: Thanks @SimonN I already have a tag for each feature that is automated (@ Before("@ Automated") but I'm sure I can add two tags such as (@ Before("@ Automated", "@ MOP") and attach the relevant @ MOP tag to the @ Before in the MOP stepdef. This makes sense. I'll give this a try shortly and report back.

Comment: @Matt I think the syntax might be @Before("@Automated, @MOP")

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Maybe post some more code? Normally you try to abstract the common behaviour into the "@Before". So if there is stuff specific for anyone test, you keep it in that test, only the general stuff is put into the "@Before" and/or "@After"

Comment: @Chai The stuff in the @ Before isn't really specific to a single test (or row from a feature in this case). It's actually just the URL that all my features from one feature file need to start on. I followed the advice from Simon above which worked. Cheers for the input everyone.

Comment: @SimonN It worked mate. Thanks! Feel free to drop your answer as an answer for me to up vote if you like.

Comment: @Matt happy it worked! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your before tag add the scenario tag so it only runs when you run that scenario i.e. @Before("@MOP") where @MOP is a tag of your feature or scenario. In your instance the syntax should be @Before("@Automated, @MOP")